# EKS: How to reduce data transfer between AZs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I am using EKS and I have 3 nodes each one in a separate availability zone. I have 2 kubernetes deployments of 2 different apps (let's name them app A and app B) with 3 replicas each, and those 2 applications have to communicate with each other. They communicate through the ClusterIP kubernetes service. So, each node has 2 pods: 1 from app A and 1 pod from app B.

What I would like to achieve is the communication of app A and app B to never leave the node, as the pods are already in the same node. Is there any way to achieve this?

I have seen on CloudWatch that communication leaves the nodes.

Comment: Check this out: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service-topology/. Specifically the https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service-topology/#prefer-node-local-endpoints section

Comment: Thanks you pointed me to the the right direction. I think though this is not supported yet by EKS because it is an alpha feature. I will see if I can find more on that.

Answer (score -2):

> What I would like to achieve is the communication of app A and app B to never leave the node, as the pods are already in the same node. Is there any way to achieve this?

Run both services as containers within the same pod, and have them communicate with one another locally.

I don't believe there's a way to use affinities or taints to achieve this reliably.

edit: Inaccurate, see docs linked in the comment on the OP's question.   Left up for completeness.

Comment: Do not do this, it's a dreadful idea. Each pod is meant to have only a single main service and some helpers. You'll find it very difficult to run multiple services in a single pod and the resistance to doing so is high.

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer yes, it's a dreadful idea, but the requirements from the original poster were for this.  I don't believe there is a way to enforce this sort of node-level exclusivity on a per-pod basis in vanilla kubernetes.  Affinities, taints, tolerations are set at the spec level and I'm not sure the operator logic is complete enough to be able to guarantee that an instance of service A and an instance of service B will cohabit on the same node - especially as your node count grows beyond 3.

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer ignore me, just saw your response above.